# In Angular 2 on submitting form not getting value of those class object which object of some other class

Tags: angular

Class is like, **User** class which **contain object of another class** i.e **Address** class as shown below:

user.ts

```
export class User {

constructor(
    public fname : string,
    public lname : string,
    public address : Address){}

}
```

address.ts

```
export class Address {

constructor(
    public address1 : string,
    public address2 : string){}
}
```

Template containing form is like

```
<form id="user" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" #f="ngForm">     

        <label>First Name :</label><br>
        <input  type="text" 
                id="first-name"
                [ngModel]="userInfo.fname"
                name="fname"
                #fname="ngModel"><br>
        <label>Last Name :</label><br>
        <input  type="text" 
                id="last-name"
                [ngModel]="userInfo.lname"
                name="lname"
                #lname="ngModel"><br>
        <label>Address1 :</label><br>
        <input  type="text" 
                id="address1"
                [ngModel]="userInfo.address.address1"
                name="address1"
                #address1="ngModel"><br>
        <label>Address2 :</label><br>
        <input  type="text" 
                id="address2"
                [ngModel]="userInfo.address.address2"
                name="address2"
                #address2="ngModel"><br>

        <button id="submit"  type="submit" ></button>

    </form>
```

and component that contain this template have following methods:

```
this.userInfo = new User("","",new Address("",""));     

onSubmit(model: User) {
  console.log("model:"+model.fname);//output correct
  console.log("model:"+model.lname);//output correct
  console.log("model:"+model.address.address1);//output error
}
```

when we submit this form,

for first two console it show output

but in last console it throw exeption

**EXCEPTION: Error in ./UserComponent class UserComponent - inline template:10:1 caused by: Cannot read property 'address1' of undefined**

Tried changing 'name' property like

`name = "address1"` or

```
name = "address.address1"
```

but getting same error

Comment: What's the output of : `console.log("model:"+model.address)` ?

Comment: cause error ,undefined

Comment: @YounesM This solved bug , got <pre> directive as plus point knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is special directive for such purposes - `ngModelGroup`. It creates a sub-group within a form.

So i would wrap your `Address` fieds in a `div` with `ngModelGroup` binding like:

```
<div ngModelGroup="address">
  <label>Address1 :</label><br>
  <input  type="text" 
          id="address1"
          [ngModel]="userInfo.address.address1"
          name="address1"
          #address1="ngModel"><br>
  <label>Address2 :</label><br>
  <input  type="text" 
          id="address2"
          [ngModel]="userInfo.address.address2"
          name="address2"
          #address2="ngModel"><br>
</div>
```

And you also have wrong binding for `address2`:

```
[ngModel]="userInfo.address2"
```

it should be:

```
[ngModel]="userInfo.address.address2"
```

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WiqijTg52cIgLE9pAZ7H?p=preview)**